# Proof about pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$: At least one of $a$ and $b$ is even.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How should I go about proving at least one of a and b is even when

$$a^2+b^2 = c^2$$

This is similar to 
[A conjecture about Pythagorean triples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678397/a-conjecture-about-pythagorean-triples), but I do not understand the steps written in there.

Could someone elaborate more please?

THanks.

Comment: HINT:  If $a$ is odd, $a^2\equiv1\pmod8$. If both are odd, $a^2+b^2\equiv2\pmod8\equiv2\pmod4$  But, $c^2\equiv0,1\pmod4$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that both $a$ and $b$ are odd.  Let's write $a=2s+1$ and $b=2t+1$.  Then
$$\eqalign{c^2
  &=a^2+b^2\cr
  &=(2s+1)^2+(2t+1)^2\cr
  &=4s^2+4s+1+4t^2+4t+1\cr
  &=4(s^2+s+t^2+t)+2\ .\cr}$$
This means that $c^2$ is even and so $c$ is even, say $c=2u$ and therefore $c^2=4u^2$.  Putting this together with the previous equation,
$$4u^2=4(s^2+s+t^2+t)+2\ .$$
Dividing by $2$ gives
$$2u^2=2(s^2+s+t^2+t)+1\ .$$
But this is impossible because the left hand side is even and the right hand side is odd.

All this can be done more easily if you have studied **modular arithmetic**.

Comment: I am just now learning modular arithmetic. Is there anyway you can explain this in terms of modular arithmetic for a beginner.

Comment: @Valentino If $x$ is any integer then $x\equiv0,1,2$ or $3\pmod4$, so $x^2\equiv0,1,4,9\equiv0,1,0,1\pmod4$.  If $a^2+b^2=c^2$ and $a,b$ are both odd then $LHS\equiv1+1\equiv2\pmod4$ but $RHS\equiv0$ or $1\pmod4$.

Answer (score 1):

If both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $a^2$ is odd, $b^2$ is odd, making $c^2=a^2+b^2$ even.

But if $c^2$ is even, then $c$ is even, which means $c^2$ is a multiple of $4$. Since two odd squares, $4n_1^2 + 4n_1+1$ and $4n_2^2+4n_2+1$ cannot add up to give a multiple of $4$, this raises a contradiction.

$\therefore$ At least one of $a$ and $b$ is even

Note that, in essence, this is the *modular arithmetic* David refers to in his answer, without using the notation of modular arithmetic, which may confuse someone who isn't familiar.

Comment: 1+3 is a multiple of 4, 15+1 is a multiple of 4. it is incorrect that two odd numbers can't add up to a multiple of 4

Comment: @GuySa Thanks for the comment. It seems I was thinking $2n_1+1 + 2n_2+1 = 4n+2$? Which is absurd.

Corrected the answer.